# At what point do I make a decision on a overworking low paying job?

Tags: management, negotiation, raise

so I've been working a cell phone repair job for a bit over a year and a half, and I've been doubting it for a long time. I took the job to get into the industry since there wasn't any opportunities around me besides this simpler one, and I don't hate this job, the issues lies in my boss and his understanding, or lack thereof, of the industry and what I'm worth. They opened this repair business with no tech understanding whatsoever.

An average repair wage for someone doing Cell Phone Repair is 13.5$ an hour, however I'm paid roughly 80% of that currently. Near or under the wage I'd get from working part time at gas stations. I do work part time at this location to fill in the location of the main tech/manager, as we have two technicians handling all 7 days a week.

As my work load and expected understanding and ability to repair has been increased, I was able to negotiate a raise with my manager of a dollar per hour after a year, however my boss reduced that 25 cents. Leaving me with an 0.75 cent raise. It's not been a year and a half on the job with no more offered raise in sight despite asking and proving my work load and expected duties are increasing, getting trusted and stressed with repairs customers pay hundreds of dollars for, and I am expected to run the shop solo some days. All check-ins, repairs, phone calls, accounting, and shipping.

I have without a doubt started looking for new jobs, however the available jobs for repair of any tech in the area is low. Tie that with the fact I can only work part time, in three, eight hour days. I managed to get into one interview at another location that didn't end up going through due to various issues.

I ultimately don't hate the job, I enjoy working with the lead tech here, I enjoy working on the devices themselves, and am fully capable of putting up with upset customers, if I'm compensated properly, which I'm not. I feel at my current work load and what I can fix, I'm worth at least a dollar per hour more.

As another note, the catalyst to write this, very recently my lead tech has gotten sick, and I've switched to working 4-5 days a week at my current wage to fill in the space. And I haven't received any compensation for doing so, nor do I expect to get any if I ask.

Ultimately I feel stuck, I'm unable to work out a higher wage due to a stubborn boss with limited tech knowledge and what it actually takes to work on these devices, but I'm also unable to land jobs anywhere else due to looking for part time jobs and the general lack of repair industry in my location. As a result of the work load, especially recently increased work load, I find myself in need of a break. The lower work hours still feel as exhausting due to the load, and I'm tempted to quit and go unemployed for the Winter, just to get a break.

Hopefully this vague explaining and question makes a modicum of sense, I'm ultimately wondering the professional way to negotiate, or if I need to seek a way to move on.

Comment: If you can do everything in the buisness, why don't you try to establish yourself as an independent buisness to do tech repairs? And possibly with your colleague if both of you don't appreciate management. I assume you have the basic skills to handle everything by this point, but may lack some funds to start.

Answer (score 3):

Forgive my lack of understanding if this is not practical, but my suggestion would be to work fewer jobs for longer time.  Instead of working 2 jobs, for 3 8-hour days at one and 2 8-hour days at the other, instead work 1 job for 5 8-hour days (if you can).  If you're finding it difficult to find 2 part-time jobs to work shorter, find 1 full-time job and work longer.  That seems to solve your main issue, which seems to be (as best I can tell) that you can't quit this job because the competing jobs want you to work more hours which would interfere with your second job.  If the money from one job is the same as from your 2 current jobs, quit both those jobs and work the one job that pays the same as those 2 combined.

As for your current situation: There is no way to "make" your boss pay you more money.  He has to believe you're worth more money, and if he doesn't, well really your only option is to find a job that will value you more.  If you go to work as a gas station attendant because you make more money that way, and the other technicians also go to be gas station attendants, then they're a tech repair shop with nobody to repair the tech; if they don't want this to happen then they have to pay you more, and that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

> his understanding, or lack thereof, of the industry and what I'm worth.

> but I'm also unable to land jobs anywhere else due to looking for part time jobs and the general lack of repair industry in my location.

**You are probably being paid what you are worth for that area then.** Just because something requires specialized knowledge does not mean that it will earn a high wage. That is doubly true when you consider that you are limited to a particular area and working particular hours/number of hours.

There is a small town in Alberta somewhat close to my city where some senior developers make about $60,000 a year. I have never made that little and I have one year of experience, nor am I a particularly skilled software engineer. If they were willing to move (or were willing to work remotely) they would earn far more.

But because they are committed to their particular area as well as to in-person work, their market value is well below what it should be because of the conditions they have for employment. It doesn't help that there are few tech jobs in small towns.

I suspect that you are stuck in the same situation and in that situation, the pay is low and future is bleak. Try and find a path forward either in some other field or some other location or some other business arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

"my boss and his understanding, or lack thereof, of the industry and what I'm worth. They opened this repair business with no tech understanding whatsoever."

Not sure it matters that they don't have tech understanding. They understand the business numbers like how much profit they're making. It's not unreasonable for someone who repairs devices to make more than the guy flipping burgers at the fast food joint down the street.

I would try to figure out what a good number is that is fair to you but not so high that they think it's crazy. They aren't going to pay you as much as the lead tech. Ask the lead guy how much he makes so you have some intel. If he's making peanuts then they're not going to be open to giving you more.

Be careful with promises tho. If the guy says he will give you a raise in a year, don't believe it. If he promises something more than 3 months out I wouldn't take it seriously.

You could consider doing your own side business where people mail you devices to fix too. You won't make a lot at first but overtime it could grow to be very rewarding. After all, you determine your own pay then.